# Will rxjs merge.complete() close subscriptions to all of its input streams?

Tags: angular, rxjs

in below case will .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe)) close subscriptions to all of input streams?

```
protected unsubscribe: Subject<void>;

public ngOnDestroy(): void {
   this.unsubscribe.next();
   this.unsubscribe.complete();
}

merge(
  this.productsSelect.selected,
  this.productsSelect.removed,
  this.productsSelect.typed)
  .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe))
  .subscribe(() => {
    this.detectChanges();
  );
```

Comment: Yes, `merge` will unsuibscribe automatically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`takeUntil` will close the subscription when the observable passed into it receives a notification.

Take this example:

```js
private destroyed$ = new Subject();
private sub: Subscription;

ngOnInit() {
  this.sub = merge(
    this.obs1(),
    this.obs2()
  ).pipe(
    takeUntil(this.destroyed$)
  ).subscribe(result => {
    console.log(result);
  }, () => {}, () => {
      console.log('complete');
  });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  // this.sub is still open
  console.log(this.sub);

  // now close the subscription indirectly
  this.destroyed$.next();
  this.destroyed$.complete();

  // this.sub is now closed
  console.log(this.sub);
}

private obs1(): Observable<any> {
  return timer(0, 1000).pipe(mapTo('Hello, '));
}

private obs2(): Observable<any> {
  return timer(0, 1500).pipe(mapTo('World!'));
}
```

While the component is in the DOM, the two observables will continue to fire and the merge subscription will receive values from the `timer` observables.

When the component is removed from the DOM, `ngOnDestroy` will fire. The first `console.log(this.sub)` will show the subscription is open. The second will show it has been closed.

From the console:

> Object { closed: false, ... }
>
> Object { closed: true, ... }

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8c9nkd

Comment: Thank you that is what I searched for :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes merge completes

**Szenario**

```
const finish$ = new Subject();
const source1$ = interval(200).pipe(mapTo('source 1'), takeUntil(finish$))
const source2$ = interval(210).pipe(mapTo('source 2'), takeUntil(finish$))
const source3$ = interval(220).pipe(mapTo('source 3'), takeUntil(finish$))

merge(
  source1$,
  source2$,
  source3$
).subscribe(
  (v) => console.info('next: ', v),
  (e) => console.error(e),
  () => console.warn('complete')
);

setTimeout(() => finish$.next(), 500);
```

**Output:**

```
next: source 1
next: source 2
next: source 3
next: source 1
next: source 2
next: source 3
complete
```

**Stackblitz**

[rxjs-merge-complete](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-merge-complete?file=src/main.ts)

Comment: You are right this is one way to do this, i was looking for answer when the input streams are not closed but only the merge itself.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question properly, then yes. The `takeUntil` operator will complete the Observable, so there will be no remaining subscriptions to inner Observables.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think...

takeUntil must be able to send and receive.

you must do like this :

```
// declare into class
unsubscribe : Subject<any>;

// into constructor
this.unsubscribe = new Subject();

// into your method
merge(
  this.productsSelect.selected,
  this.productsSelect.removed,
  this.productsSelect.typed)
  .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe))
  .subscribe(() => {
    this.detectChanges();
);

ngOnDestroy(): void {
  this.unsubscribe.next();
  this.unsubscribe.complete();
}
```